# Adding Variable Length Cells to total formula in R1C1 in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula that creates x number of columns of data as per the calculated number of months a project is going to span.  I am trying to formulate a macro to enter the formula into a cell to calculate the cells.  The number of columns it will need to add will vary from project to project.
I have attempted some of the script, but am stumped at how to proceed with it, but still trying.

[Columns to be calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJLsr.png)

```
Sub Totals()

Dim SumRange As Integer
Dim AddCell As Range

Sheets("Tracking (DAYS)").Select
Sheets("Tracking (DAYS)").Range("E4").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0))

Set AddCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF([@[Resource Name]]="""",""""," & AddCell & ")"


Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. In E4 you want the sum of your forecast calendar ?

Comment: Sorry difficult to explain.

But in short, I'm seeking to add all the columns that are Forecast Calendar.  Now the number of columns it will need to add will vary depending on how many months the project is expected to run for.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess solution:

```
Sub Totals()
    Lc = Sheets("Tracking (DAYS)").Cells(3, 999).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheets("Tracking (DAYS)").Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R3C8:R3C" & Lc & ",""*(Forecast) Calendar"",R4C8:R4C" & Lc & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Mostly works.  How do I remove the "$" from the "R4C8:R4C" section?

Comment: Just remove the 4 : `...RC8:RC" & Lc & ")"`

Comment: Sorry to be an absolute pain, but would you be able to help explain how this formula works?
I ask, because I'm adapting it to the other sheets I need to apply this to.

Thank you again!

Comment: What do you mean by "this formula" ? More detail for : [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b), [R1C1](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm)